# Combining tab delimited files based on a column value

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Suppose I have two tab-delimited files that share a column. Both files have a header line that gives a label to each column. What's an easy way to take the union of the two tables, i.e. take the columns from A and B, but do so according to the value of column K?

for example, table A might be:

```
employee_id  name
123   john
124   mary
```

and table B might be:

```
employee_id  age
124  18
123  22
```

then the union based on column 1 of table A ("employee_id") should yield the table:

```
employee_id  name  age
123  john  22
124  mary  18
```

i'd like to do this using Unix utilities, like "cut" etc.  how can this be done?

Comment: why is John having age of 18 and not 22 ? typo?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the `join` utility, but your files need to be sorted first.

```
join file1 file2
```

`man join` for more information

Answer (score 4):

here's a start. I leave you to format the headers as needed

```
$ awk 'NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2}END{for(i in a)print a[i],i}' tableA.txt tableB.txt
 age employee_id
 john 22 123
 mary 18 124
```

another way

```
$ join <(sort tableA.txt) <(sort tableB.txt)
123 john 22
124 mary 18
employee_id name age
```

experiment with the join options when needed (see info page or man page)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
paste file1 file2 > file3
```